# Can I use Git Bash to copy script from another directory to the working directory?

Tags: git, bash

I need to write down a code in my script so when I run it in Bash it copies file x from directory D to the working directory. System: Windows 7 64-bit.

**The first script is to create a directory and initiate git repos**,

```bash
mkdir "directory"
# Create directory

cd directory
# Change directory

git init
# initial git repository

touch README
git add README
# add readme file

git commit -m 'add README'
# commit the changes of the readme file
############################################
# . cdir.sh to run the first script and change the wd to the new one
```

**The second script to create github repos**,

```bash
curl -u 'username' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d \
'{"name":"REPO","description":"This project is a test"}' 
# Create repository on github
# Remember replace REPO with your repository/application name!

git remote add "origin" git@github.com:ahmedfsalhin/REPO.git
# Remember replace REPO with your repository/application name!

git push origin master
# Push to the origin remote (github) from the master local branch
```

To run the second script I need to first copy and paste it in the new working directory created above. I need to combine the two scripts so I can `sh` only one script.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? What didn't work? Stack Overflow isn't a job board, it's a site to help people with specific programming questions.

Comment: Yes I did two scripts one for creating local directory and initiate git repos on it and the other one for creating a github repo and remote my local one. The issue is that I need to combine these scripts in only one script. The problem is that the second script should be run from inside the directory I have made by the first script. So I need to write a line at the end of the first script so it copies the second script in the new directory and run the second script.

Comment: There's almost certainly a better way to do this, e.g. maybe just `cd` into the target directory and run your script. Instead of three scripts duct taped together you can probably have a single script. Can you post the scripts here?

Comment: Chris, I added it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to combine the scripts during execution of the first is to `source` the second script into the first thereby copying it verbatim into the first script at the point of the `source` or `.` call:

```
git commit -m 'add README'
# commit the changes of the readme file
############################################
# . cdir.sh to run the first script and change the wd to the new one

# test 2nd script exists and source second script into first
test -r "/path/to/second/script" && \
source /path/to/second/script   # you can also use . /path/to/second/script
```